# Controllable Azure Worker Role Crash Recovery

Tags: c#, azure, windows-services, azure-cloud-services

We are in progress of Windows Service to Azure Cloud Service Worker Role migration and wondering about automatic crash recovery available in Azure.

Previously, Windows Service crash recovery was configured using Service Controller. There is known user-interface to manage the rules(see below).

In Azure seems it's uncontrollable how exactly crashes of Worker Role will be handled. Is there something similar to Windows Services Recovery in Azure Cloud Services?

[image: Win Services Recovery Options UI]

Comment: having worked meany times with worker roles when a crash happens the worker role instance will be reinitialized and launched again , as far as i know we can't really control it unless using try, catch blocks to avoid crashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both web and worker roles will unconditionally recycle whenever there's an unhandled exception in `RoleEntryPoint` `Run()` method or the role entry point process exits. If there's a new exception it will recycle again. The recycle process includes restarting the role process and optionally cleaning up the "local storage" resources. Maybe there's some upper limit on the number of restarts but I've never managed to hit it - I've seen dozens of restarts in row when there was a repeatable problem.